# How to work with variable with different datatype in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have variable with a type as

```
let campaigns : {
  [key: string] : string[]
} | string[] = []
```

As we can see in a logic variable is either one or another type. When I know for sure in my logic that is an array I will try to use as `campaigns.push("string")`. But I will get Typescript error as saying that you can't use push on object, cause typescript doesn't know that in my logic I illuminated a chance on been an object. How let Typescript know that `campaign.push()` is a legal operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please do like this:

```
const arrOrObj: Record<string, string> | string[] = []

if (Array.isArray(arrOrObj)) arrOrObj.push("a")
```

Or you can use a type checking function:

```
function isArrayString(arr: object): arr is string[] {
  return typeof arr === "object" && "length" in arr
}
```

`is` allows you to specify how the type of a variable is defined. That is, when the function returns true, the variable declared on the left will have the type on the right. That is when

```
if (isArrayString(arr)) {
  // arr is string[] <-- The type that `is` specifies in the return . declaration
} else {
  // arr is other type
}
```